# d3 adding data attribute conditionally

Tags: d3.js

I'm creating a table with d3 to be used by the [FooTable jquery plugin](http://css-tricks.com/footable-a-jquery-plugin-for-responsive-data-tables/) and this requires having some data- attributes in the header row.  But not all columns have all the data attributes and wondering if there is a way to do this.

This approach sort of works, by adding all the possible data attributes and leaving some blank, but I'm sure it's not good practise.

```
var th = d3.select(selection).select("thead").selectAll("th")
            .data(colspec)
            .enter().append("th")
            .text(function(d) { return d["data-name"]; })
            .attr("data-class", function(d) {
                if ("data-class" in d) {
                    return d["data-class"];
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            })
            .attr("data-hide", function(d) {
                if ("data-hide" in d) {
                    return d["data-hide"];
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            })
            .attr("data-ignore", function(d) {
                if ("data-ignore" in d) {
                    return d["data-ignore"];
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            })

       etc.
```

colspec example:

```
[{"data-name": "username"}, {"data-name": "Date Joined", "data-hide": "true"}]
```

Currently getting:

```
  <th data-class="" data-hide="true" data-ignore="" data-type="">Joined</th>
```

Want

```
   <th  data-hide="true" >Joined</th>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: +1'd just for introducing me to FooTable

Comment: So if I got the question straight, when a certain cell has no data, you would like the _minified_ version of the table to **not** show the field, right?

Comment: Not try to be that clever (yet!)  Added comment above.

Comment: Yes, only just found footable myself!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Seems like a good candidate for `.each()`:

```
var th = d3.select(selection).select("thead").selectAll("th")
        .data(colspec)
    .enter().append("th")
        .text(function(d) { return d["data-name"]; })
        // now address each item individually
        .each(function(d) {
            var header = d3.select(this);
            // loop through the keys - this assumes no extra data
            d3.keys(d).forEach(function(key) {
                if (key != "data-name")
                    header.attr(key, d[key]);
            });
        });
```

I often use `.each` when having a per-item scope makes more sense than trying to figure out a bunch of attributes for each item.

For a short list of attributes, especially if you're worried about extra data in the objects, it's probably easier to loop through the desired keys instead of everything:

```
        .each(function(d) {
            var header = d3.select(this);
            ['data-class', 'data-hide', 'data-ignore'].forEach(function(key) {
                if (key in d)
                    header.attr(key, d[key]);
            });
        });
```

Comment: why do you need a forEach inside a .each?

Comment: .each loops through the data objects (rows), while in this example forEach is looping through attributes to be applied to each item (cols).

Answer (score 69):

You don't need to call each() or filter()...  The attr() function will do this for you internally.  Just call it with a function instead of a value, and have that function return the desired value for each datum, or null if the attribute is not desired for a particular datum, like so:

```
...
.attr('data-class', function(d) {
    return 'data-class' in d ? d['data-class'] : null;
});
```

If your function returns null, the attribute is not added.  You can even combine several attributes into one call by providing a map of attr names to functions like so:

```
...
.attr({
    'data-class': function(d) {
        return 'data-class' in d ? d['data-class'] : null;
    }, 
    'data-hide': function(d) {
        return 'data-hide' in d ? d['data-hide'] : null;
    },
    'data-ignore': function(d) {
        return 'data-ignore' in d ? d['data-ignore'] : null;
    }
});
```

or if you're like me and would rather not type so much, you can reduce the list of attribute names into the appropriate map:

```
...
.attr(['data-class', 'data-hide', 'data-ignore'].reduce(function(result, attr) {
    result[attr] = function(d) {
        return attr in d ? d[attr] : null;
    }
    return result;
}, {}));
```

Comment: +1 for specifying that a null attribute is not added

Comment: this works well if there are slight variations for rendering based on the data. If you want to render a completely different object based on some data key, I think .each() is more succinct.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`.filter()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter) function to only operate on the subset of the selection that you need to set attributes for, e.g.

```
var th = d3.select(selection).select("thead").selectAll("th")
        .data(colspec)
        .enter().append("th")
        .text(function(d) { return d["data-name"]; });
th.filter(function(d) { return ("data-class" in d); })
        .attr("data-class", function(d) {
            return d["data-class"];
        });
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to cycle through the elements six times (number of data attributes), although the filter idea will make it less onerous.  There is no way to do it inline in one pass?

Comment: Another approach would be to simply call a function on each element that does the switching and attribute setting. This way, you would only touch each element once.

Answer (score 1):

The most voted solution is perfect because `.attr(a,b)` works as conditional when `b` is null,

```
 d3chain.attr('data-class', d=>'data-class' in d ? d['data-class'] : null );
```

but this solution is not geral, **is not valid for other chaining methods**, except using `.each()`, `.filter` or `.call()`.  In general the most simple is `call()`.

### .call(condFunc,param)

Suppose that `param` is an global variable used as parameter in the condition, and that  `g` is a global object used to return a value.

```
  // inconditional
  d3chain.attr(param, g[param])

  // conditional case using globals
  d3chain.call( s => { if (g[param]) s.attr(param,g[param]) })

  // conditional case passing the parameter
  d3chain.call( (s,p) => {
     if (g[p]) s.attr(p, g[p])
  }, param)
```

### .each(d => condFunc)

Typical use:

```
 d3chain.each( d=> {
     if (param && d) d3.select(this).attr(d, g[param])
 })
```

See @nrabinowitz answer for detailed example.

### .filter(d=>condFunc).etc

Typical use:

```
 d3chain.filter( d=> param in d ).attr(param, d=> g[param])
```

See @LarsKotthoff answer for detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner is to use filter

```
.filter(d => !!d["data-class"]) // filter only data with the "data-class" property
.attr("data-class", d => d["data-class"])
```