# How to add different shape marker in d3?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I try to add different shape size marker (for example, triangle ,rectangle,circle)in D3 svg ,
for example , if level is admin ,the marker shape is circle
if level is member ,the marker shape is triangle
if level is guest ,the marker shape is rectangle
I try to using gooup.each

```
var groups = svg
  .style("overflow", "visible")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" +  projection([d.lon,d.lat])+ ")";});

groups.each(function(d) {
var elem = d3.select(this);

  if (d.level == "admin") {

    elem.append("rect").attr("width", 5).attr("height", 5)
    .style("fill",function() {
    return "red";
    });
  }
 if (d.level == "member") {
 elem.append("path").attr("d", 'M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z').attr('transform','scale(0.04) translate(-150,-130)')
  .style("fill",function() {
    return "green";
    });
  }
 if (d.level == "guest") {
elem.append("circle").attr("r", 4).attr('cy',2).attr('cx',2)        
.style("fill",function() {return "yellow";});
  }
});
```

But it's cannot show the first data from the data array,

from [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/mattcrawfoord/Lzya029a/2/) ,as you can see ,it's cannot display the first data in the data array, but I'm not sure how to modify. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: See this QA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205034/d3-adding-data-attribute-conditionally

Comment: Also: [*"how to directly use data injected into d3 selectors via .data?"*](/q/39278704).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append groups `g` - element to the svg , loop over that groups and append different shapes to it

take a look of the snippet down

```html
 <div id='graphContent'></div>
  
  <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'></script>

    <script>
    var selector = "#graphContent";

var data = [{ level: "admin" }, { level: "admin" },{ level: "member" }, { level: "guest" },{ level: "admin" }];

var groups = d3
  .select("#graphContent")
  .append("svg")
  .style("overflow", "visible")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", (d, i) => `translate(0,${i * 20})`);

groups.each(function(d) {
  var elem = d3.select(this);

  if (d.level == "admin") {
    //rectangle
    elem.append("rect").attr("width", 5).attr("height", 5);
  }
  if (d.level == "member") {
    //triangle
    //svg does not have triangle shape , so we use path to draw it
     elem.append("path").attr("d", 'M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z').attr('transform','scale(0.04) translate(-150,-130)')
  }
  if (d.level == "guest") {
    //circle
    elem.append("circle").attr("r", 4).attr('cy',2).attr('cx',2);
  }
});
  </script>
```

Comment: I have modify my code as you said , but still cannot work . you can see my code from http://jsfiddle.net/mattcrawfoord/Lzya029a/  . but I'm not sure how to modify. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: here is updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lzya029a/1/  you were appending svg second time, I also suggest to set different color to the different level

Comment: also, I have css in the fiddle, pls take a look of that also

Comment: @bumbeishivli,I really appreciate your help! But I found a problem about your code, it's cannot show the first data from data array ,for example the first data is member,but it's cannot shown from jsfiddle.net/mattcrawfoord/Lzya029a/2

Comment: are you sure?
all 3 member triangles are displayed -  http://jsfiddle.net/6n472rk9/
please, see that, I have changed css and added class for groups

Comment: @bumbeishivli,but the first data (admin) didn't displayed. as you can see ,didn't display rectangle for admin

Comment: ok, figured it out,

there already was a g element in svg, so just change `.selectAll("g")` with 
`.selectAll(".group")` .  here is updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6n472rk9/3/

Comment: @georgetovrea were you able to fix that?

Comment: @bumbeishivli, thanks for you help,I have fix the problem